# Parsing information from PHP Object

Tags: php, wordpress

I need some help trying to parse informaiton ti display in a form.  Right now when using the basic array an address is returned as "3 Columbus PlaceApt1" where Address 1 and Address 2 are returned joined together.  I created an object that returns this with print_r

```
a:2:{
    s:18:"_gravity_form_lead";a:16:{
        s:4:"19.1";s:28:"Stamford PD Extra Duty Order";s:4:"19.2";s:5:"$0.00";s:4:"19.3";s:0:"";s:3:"9.1";s:16:"3 Columbus Place";s:3:"9.2";s:5:"Apt 1";s:3:"9.3";s:0:"";s:3:"9.4";s:11:"Connecticut";s:3:"9.5";s:0:"";s:3:"9.6";s:13:"United States";i:22;s:14:"(203) 123-4567";i:12;s:10:"2016-05-24";i:13;s:8:"12:35 am";i:20;s:8:"8|584.64";i:11;s:9:"MH6151684";i:21;s:1:"3";i:18;s:7:"1753.92";}s:18:"_gravity_form_data";a:15:{s:2:"id";s:1:"6";s:13:"display_title";b:0;s:19:"display_description";b:0;s:25:"disable_woocommerce_price";s:3:"yes";s:12:"price_before";s:0:"";s:11:"price_after";s:0:"";s:20:"disable_calculations";s:2:"no";s:22:"disable_label_subtotal";s:3:"yes";s:21:"disable_label_options";s:3:"yes";s:19:"disable_label_total";s:2:"no";s:14:"disable_anchor";s:2:"no";s:14:"label_subtotal";s:8:"Subtotal";s:13:"label_options";s:7:"Options";s:11:"label_total";s:5:"Total";s:8:"use_ajax";s:2:"no";
    }
}
```

I want to parse our s:16 and s:5 but im not sure how to do it.  Any help is appreciated

**EDIT**

Unserialized string:

```
array ( '_gravity_form_lead' => array ( '19.1' => 'Stamford PD Extra Duty Order', '19.2' => '$0.00', '19.3' => '', '9.1' => '3 Columbus Place', '9.2' => 'Apt 1', '9.3' => '', '9.4' => 'Connecticut', '9.5' => '', '9.6' => 'United States', 22 => '(203) 123-4567', 12 => '2016-05-24', 13 => '12:35 am', 20 => '8|584.64', 11 => 'MH6151684', 21 => '3', 18 => '1753.92', ), '_gravity_form_data' => array ( 'id' => '6', 'display_title' => false, 'display_description' => false, 'disable_woocommerce_price' => 'yes', 'price_before' => '', 'price_after' => '', 'disable_calculations' => 'no', 'disable_label_subtotal' => 'yes', 'disable_label_options' => 'yes', 'disable_label_total' => 'no', 'disable_anchor' => 'no', 'label_subtotal' => 'Subtotal', 'label_options' => 'Options', 'label_total' => 'Total', 'use_ajax' => 'no', ), )
```

Comment: Since you were able to serialize your data, you should be able to unserialize it... no? Do you at least have any idea what this representation stands for?

Comment: To be honest im not even sure what that string of text is, I'm using gravity forms + woocommerce to bring in extra data when a person makes a purchase, but the odd thing is that it concatenates Address and Address 2 fields into 1 string.  Those representations are just the entry data for that form

Comment: To complement Arcesilas's comment, please show us the output of `var_export(unserialize($var));`.

Comment: Oh this is much easier to read, adding it to the main comment

Comment: This string is a serialized array: a string representation of the array. `a` stands for `array`, `s` for `string`. The number after an `a` is the number of items in the array, the number after `s` is the length of the string.

Comment: Right, so in this case I want '9.1' and '9.2' in two different strings, so by removing the var_export from var_export(unserialize($gform)); i can just treat this as a regular object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to unserialize the array to get the data you need. Like this:

```
$formData = unserialize($var);

// This is Address1
echo $formData['_gravity_form_lead']['9.1'];

echo "<br/>";

// This is Address2
echo $formData['_gravity_form_lead']['9.2'];
```

Answer (score 4):

You're doing this the hard way!

This is WordPress.  You don't need to get a record, unserialize it, try and guess at the structure, etc.

Instead, use the [get_option](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) or [get_postmeta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) functions to get the information you want.

Further, there's documentation for both WooCommerce and Gravity Forms that will explain how to get the information you're looking for - BUT,  this is a bit of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you've asked how to parse an array (Serialized) - but REALLY you are trying to do something else.  You should ask THAT question, rather than the details of this question.

If you **must** do this manually, do not use `unserialize`. Instead, use the WordPress function [maybe_unserialize](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize)

Lastly, the way Gravity Forms stores records is a major nuisance.  It's very difficult to map the way it is stored to the "form field" that you set up in the form - unless you use the [Gravity Forms API](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gravity-forms-api/), which makes it somewhat better.

Comment: Agree 200% (at least). Thanks for the link about XY problem!

Comment: Hey Cale, Thanks for the heads up.  It's weird because this is a mesh between Gravity forms and WooCommerce so trying to find the correct hooks to get the data is driving me insane.  I will try to dig a little deeper into both documentations to see what the better approach is and apply it once i have more knowledge

Comment: @DavidMoran - happy to help, if you can provide a higher-level "question" that says something like "when a user places an order, GF does X, using [whatever] plugin, and I'd like to get the foobar record that GF saves" (or whatever is actually happening!)

Comment: @cale_b this may sound like a noob question, but do you have any recommendations for learning how to work with APIs?  I've done a lot of front end coding but never needed to use an API before.